# Textview not wrapping text

Tags: android, textview

I used all possible ways to wrap text in `textview` but it's not working. It's only showing one line and the rest is gone. I'm fetching address from database and assigning it to `textview`. I tried `textview`'s `height` and `width` parameters with all possible values but it's still not working.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="match_parent" android:gravity="fill_horizontal">
<TextView android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/address" 
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/address" android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/address" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/addressans" 
    android:layout_marginLeft="55dp"
    android:inputType="textMultiLine"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:ellipsize="none"
    android:singleLine = "false"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content">
</TextView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's coz you specified both `android:layout_alignTop="@+id/address"` and `android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/address"`. Your `TextView` has no space to stretch. You probably need to remove `android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/address"` attribute to let it stretch to the bottom.

Comment: @ernazm-true wat u said but the thing is if i remove those attributes then i is not maintainig position its is jus going newhere

Comment: Are you sure you have a view with `id=@+id/address` in that `RelativeLayout`?

Comment: its done.i got it.thnx alot man..i spent many hours in finding y this is happning..thnx alot